# Auto proxy switcher WInform (C#)

Tags: c#, winforms

I am new to **C#** and I'm trying to build an app using it.

On my app, there is an option to use proxies on the web browser.
I've already found a way to use proxies on the web browser. **How it works:** the user pastes a single IP: Port proxy and after they click on the *start button* the app tells the web browser to use the specified proxy server.

**! Issue:** The problem is I want the app to switch proxies after a certain amount of time.

I concept that I have is: a `textbox` where the user can paste a list of proxies, and after the user click on the starts button the app will tell the web browser to use the proxy on the first line.

After (*let's say*) 30 seconds, it will automatically switch to the second line and so on, till the user clicks on the stop button.

Basically, it will be switching vertically to a new line after a certain amount of time.

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please take a minute to take the [tour], especially [ask], and [edit] your question accordingly.

Comment: Add a timer.  See msdn : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timers.timer?view=netframework-4.7.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Add timer control.

Refer the below code

```
List<string> lstIpAddress = new List<string>();
int nCount = 0;

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   timer1.Interval = 30000;
}

 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
        string strIp = textBox1.Text;
        if (strIp.Length > 0)
        {
            lstIpAddress = strIp.Split(',').ToList();
            for (int nlstItem = 0; nlstItem < lstIpAddress.Count; nlstItem++)
            {
                listBox1.Items.Add(lstIpAddress[nlstItem]);
            }
            //Pass the IP to Web Browser
            label2.Text = listBox1.Items[nCount].ToString();
            nCount++;
        }
        timer1.Start();
 }

 private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
        timer1.Stop();
        //Pass the IP to Web Browser
        label2.Text = listBox1.Items[nCount].ToString();
        timer1.Start();
 }
```

[image: IP Address]

Comment: Thank you, But is there a way to split them without adding a comma?

Comment: not just comma you can use any character but the other ways is to add each IP and click add Button one by one.

Comment: But can I separate it without any characters?

Comment: If you don't want to separate with any character you must have to get IP One by One